# KaTeX does not render math between dollars sign on not the same line

Tags: rendering, ace-editor, katex

I want to create an editor with ace + katex. Problem is that double dollars sign does not compiles correctly

For example:

Good

`$$\mathcal D = 25+4\cdot6\cdot1=49=7^2$$`

Bad

```
$$
\mathcal D = 25+4\cdot6\cdot1=49=7^2
$$
```

Katex render options:

```
renderMathInElement(this.katexView, { delimiters: [
      {left: "$$", right: "$$", display: true},
      {left: "$", right: "$", display: false},
    ]});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found my mistake, I inserted text for katex node via `innerText`, but katex need `innerHTML`

Answer (score -1):

Why not use directly the equation / align environments?

```
\begin{equation}
\mathcal D = 25+4\cdot6\cdot1=49=7^2
\end{equation}
```

Or simply

```
\[ 
\mathcal D = 25+4\cdot6\cdot1=49=7^2
\]
```

Comment: Not sure if I understood your answer, quite a lot of people will write in this editor and everyone uses the method described above.
For the first method, in any case, you need to describe delimiters